# Should I use StandardScaler on non-stationary data?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, standardization

When I'm using [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) on non-stationary data, like exponential global temperature, I use it as follows:

```
scaler_x = StandardScaler()
X_train_mms = scaler_x.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_mms = scaler_x.transform(X_test)

scaler_y = StandardScaler()
y_train_std = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_test_std = scaler_y.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

My questions are:

In details my data is a monthly temperature time series data, using features from the last time step and the previous year's time step for temperature (months as categorical variables, and CO<sub>2</sub>).

If I use the scaling only on `X_train` (and transform on `X_test`) I get really bad results. So I used the scaling also on the target values `y`, but then I thought if I use it also on `y`,when i am going back to validate the model(when I inverse the results back with `scaler_y`):

1. Am I not giving information which I am not supposed to the model, and that's why the model is better?

or actually

2. I am not supposed to use [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) on non-stationary data at all?

The problem is also co2 scale is much bigger than the temperature, so I have to scale it ,I just wonder if it is correct or I should try another way.